# Is it meaningful to control for variables that are correlated with the independent and dependent variables?

Tags: causality, controlling-for-a-variable

Statistical training from the National Institute of Child Health and Human Development states:

> A general (usually unquestioned) assumption is that differences on "nuisance" variables that are correlated with the independent and dependent variables should be statistically controlled to avoid interpreting "spurious" findings.

Edit: and here's a 2014 [textbook](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-05470-4):

[image]

I cannot make sense of this criterion. I would generally think you'd want to control for variables that have a direct causal effect on the independent variable. More specifically...

Taking $X$ and $Y$ as the independent & dependent variables, and $V$ as the possible nuisance variable, and using $\rightarrow$ to mark **direct** causation, one wants to determine if $V \rightarrow Y$. But if $X \rightarrow Y$ then the criterion will typically:

- pick up cases with $V \rightarrow X$ but $V \nrightarrow Y$.
- miss cases where $V \rightarrow X$ and $V \rightarrow Y$, and the causal effects $V \rightarrow X \rightarrow Y$ and $V \rightarrow Y$ cancel out.

I.e. it seems to be neither necessary nor sufficient.

The criterion also seems to raise problems with post-selection inference.

**Am I missing something? Is there some solid rationale behind the stated advice?** It's used in some papers that have had a major influence on policy.

FWIW, I have read the answers to [When is it inappropriate to control for a variable?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/325900/when-is-it-inappropriate-to-control-for-a-variable), which make me lean towards trusting my original judgment, but I'd still be grateful for confirmation...

Comment: It's probably not sufficient but it is necessary. Take a look at DAGs. Cunningham provides an introduction here: https://mixtape.scunning.com/03-directed_acyclical_graphs

Comment: Let's say you want to estimate the causal effect of chewing gum on mortality. Smoking is a confounder because smoking makes people more likely to chew gum and decrease mortality. You'd need to adjust for smoking.